# How do you change the primary key sent to an update view in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to change the primary key being sent to the update view from the template. Let me explain. Here is my template:

```
<a href="{% url 'new_url' model_instance.pk %}">
    {{ model_instance.username }}
</a>
```

This `model_instance` is an instance in a for loop of the context variable `model_instances` in a list view. This primary key of the model_instance will then be sent to the following view:

```
class UserUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    template_name = "leads/update.html"
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    context_object_name = "user"
    form_class = UserUpdateForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("some-url")
```

However, the problem is that the primary key I am sending to `UserUpdateView` is the primary key for the `model_instance` model, not the `User` model. Moreover, there is no link like one-to-one relationships between the two models. However, there is a similarity. Both of the `model_instance` and `user` each have a `username` field that are the same.

In other words, I need to first retrieve the `model_instance.username`, and then query the `User` model to find the `user` instance with the same `username` I want to update. At the moment, the `UserUpdateView` is simply receiving the primary key for a `model_instance` in the template, which is not what I want. I hope you guys can help me with this issue, and please leave any questions you have. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not intuitive enough but yes it is possible. It's also good to mention that you define a `queryset` attribute in the view, if you want update only one object then it's not necessary.
You can override the `get_object` method to do this :

```
class UserUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    template_name = "leads/update.html"
    # queryset = User.objects.all()
    context_object_name = "user"
    form_class = UserUpdateForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("some-url")
    
    def get_object(self):
        # Here w'll retrieve the correct object to update
        
        # First we retrieve the username of the model_instance
        model_instance = ModelInstance.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        username = model_instance.username  # Retrieve the username
        
        # After, retrieve the user with username=model_instance.username
        # Normally, the username must be unique per model_instance and per user. If not an error can be trowed.
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        # If username is not unique, try this approach
        # user = User.objects.filter(username=username).first()

        # Return the user object
        return user
```

This template link :

```
<a href="{% url 'new_url' model_instance.pk %}">
    {{ model_instance.username }}
</a>
```

will now point out the user to update, not the model_instance.

More about [get_object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object)

Comment: Hey, did you return `user` because of `user = User.objects.get(username=username)`? If you defined it as `somethingelse = User.objects.get(username=username)`, then should I return `somethignelse`?

Comment: @code builder, yes of course

Answer (score 1):

Since model_instance and user have the same username, you could pass in the `model_instance.username` when generating the url and change your UpdateView to specify `slug_field = "username"`. You would also have to change your urlconfig to use "slug" instead of "pk" or add `slug_url_kwarg = "pk"` .

```
<a href="{% url 'new_url' model_instance.username %}">
    {{ model_instance.username }}
</a>
class UserUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    template_name = "leads/update.html"
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    context_object_name = "user"
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    slug_field = "username"
    slug_url_kwarg = "pk"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("some-url")
```